# Why doesnt my dispatch for axios POST work?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=431EvDGKwks&list=PLillGF-RfqbbiTGgA77tGO426V3hRF9iE&index=7) to learn redux.

My addItem action dispatch doesnt work but getItem action dispatch works. Axios post works and Data gets added to DB but dispatch doesnt work so list isnt updated. Only when i refresh the page when list gets updated.
Api is also correct and required response comes while checking from Postman.

addItem only works when axios is not used and list are updated for storing in local store.

itemActions.js

```
export const getItems = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setItemLoading());
    axios
        .get('/api/items')
        .then(res =>
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ITEMS,
                payload: res.data
            })
        )
};
export const addItem = item => (dispatch) => {
    axios.post('/api/items', item).then(res =>
        dispatch({
            type: ADD_ITEM,
            payload: res.data
        })
    );
};
```

router.js

```
//@route GET api/items
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    Item.find().sort({date:-1}).then(items=>res.json(items))
});


//@route POST api/items
router.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    const newItem = new Item({
        name:req.body.name
    });
    newItem.save().then(item=>res.json(item));
});

module.exports = router;
```

ItemReducer.js

```
    const initialState={
        items:[],
        loading:false
    };

const itemReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_ITEMS:
            return {
                ...state,
                items:action.payload,
                loading: false
        };

        case ADD_ITEM:
            return {
                ...state,
                items: [action.payload, ...state.items]
            };
      
        default: return state
    }
};

export default itemReducer
```

itemModal.js

(form submit)

```
import { addItem} from '../actions/itemActions';
     
onSubmit = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const newItem = {
                name: this.state.name
            };
            // Add item via addItem action
            this.props.addItem(newItem);
            // Close modal
            this.toggle();
        };
```

(dispatch)

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    addItem: (item) => dispatch(addItem(item))
});

export default connect(
    null,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(ItemModal);
```

ItemList.js (List renedered here)

```
import {getItems} from "../actions/itemActions";

class ShoppingList extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getItems()
    }

    render() {
        const {items}=this.props.item;
        return (
            <Container>
                 <ul>
                        {items.map(({_id,name})=><li key={_id} >
                            <p>{name}&nbsp;</p>
                        </li>)}
                </ul>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state =>{
    return{
        item: state.item,
    }
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps,{getItems})(ItemList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dispatch any action after adding item, just fetch the whole list to update the store and re-render the component.

**UPDATE:** Please check the ItemModal onSubmit function. Check the sanbox for reference. https://codesandbox.io/s/list-renderer-gm7hi

itemActions.js

```
  export const getItems = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setItemLoading());
    axios
        .get('/api/items')
        .then(res =>
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ITEMS,
                payload: res.data
            })
         )
  };
```

router.js

```
//@route GET api/items
router.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    Item.find().sort({date:-1}).then(items=>res.json(items))
});


//@route POST api/items
router.post('/',(req,res)=>{
    const newItem = new Item({
        name:req.body.name
    });
    newItem.save().then(()=>res.status(200));
});

module.exports = router;
```

ItemReducer.js

```
  const initialState={
        items:[],
        loading:false
    };

const itemReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case GET_ITEMS:
            return {
                ...state,
                items:action.payload,
                loading: false
        };
      
        default: return state
    }
};

export default itemReducer
```

ItemModal.js

(form submit) assuming you have created state for input

```
import { getItems} from '../actions/itemActions';
import axios from 'axios';
     
onSubmit = e => {
            e.preventDefault();
            axios
              .post("/api/items", {
                 name: this.state.newItem
               })
              .then(() => this.props.getItems());
            // Close modal
            this.toggle();
        };
```

(dispatch) don't need to define extra function

```
export default connect(
    null,
    { getItems }
)(ItemModal);
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Nope doesnt refresh. Checked using redux tool extension. getItem dispatch doesnt work after addItem post is done.

Comment: Okay, please upload component code of the Items, in which items are displaying. you need to use a useEffect in that component. I'm using this type of refresh in my own various components after adding data to DB.

Comment: Please check the updated code. for reference, I've created a sandbox for you
https://codesandbox.io/s/list-renderer-gm7hi

Comment: Turns out my post request to db is the culprit. Checked again with postman and data gets added to mongodb but response is loading forever just for post request.

Comment: I think that's for not setting the status code in response.